# Fast Fourier Transform C++

Tags: c++, math, fft

I'm trying to reproduce this program flowchart [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miL3G.png) in C++ to calculate the FFT of an array.
I know it is supposed to be straightforward to follow, but I keep getting different results from what I should. I reanalysed every complex multiplication to conform to the algorithm and it seems to be fine but it doesn't calculate de results properly.
I know there are 'modern' and maybe simpler methods of doing this using modules including the 'complex' one, but I want to understand why this doesn't work.
One of the test cases I tried is:

{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1} and I got this:

```
40 0 0 0 -1.75736 -6.54712 -8.61313 -7.08239 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 <- real
0 0 0 0 4.24264 -2.71191 -8.61313 7.08239 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 <- imaginary
```

when I was supposed to get this:
`(40,0) (0,0) (-11.6569,-4.82843) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (-0.343146,-0.828427) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (-0.343146,0.828427) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (-11.6569,4.82843) (0,0)`
This is the code that I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


double xreal[100] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1}, ximag[100];
int gamma = 4;

int itbtr(int m);

void fft(int gamma, double xreal[100], double ximag[100]){
    int n2, nu1;
    int N = 1<<gamma;
 
    int l = 1;
    n2 = N/2;
    nu1 = gamma - 1;
    int k = 0;


    while(l <= gamma) {
        while(k < N) {
            int I = 1;
            while(I <= n2)
            {
                int M = int(k >> nu1);
                int P = itbtr(M);
  
                double arg = 6.283185 * P / N;

                double cosarg = cos(arg);
                double sinarg = sin(arg);

                double treal = cosarg * xreal[k + n2] - ximag[k + n2] * sinarg;
                double timag = sinarg * xreal[k + n2] + cosarg * ximag[k + n2];

                xreal[k + n2] = xreal[k] - treal;
                ximag[k + n2] = ximag[k] - timag;

                xreal[k] = xreal[k] + treal;
                ximag[k] = ximag[k] + timag;

                k++;
                I++;
            }
            k += n2;
        }
        l++;
        n2 /= 2;
        nu1 --;
        k = 0;
    }

    if(l > gamma){
        while(k <= N - 1){
            int i = itbtr(k);
            if(i > k) swap(xreal[k], xreal[i]), swap(ximag[k], ximag[i]);
            k ++ ;
        }
    }
}

//bit reversal
int itbtr(int k){
    int m = k;
    int newn = 0;
    while(m){
        newn *= 2;
        newn += m % 2;
        m /= 2;
    }
    return newn;
}


int main(){
    fft(gamma, xreal, ximag);
    for(int i = 0; i < pow(2, gamma); i++)
    cout<<xreal[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < pow(2, gamma); i++)
    cout<<ximag[i]<<" ";
}
```

If anybody can help, I would be very thankful.

The flowchart that I was following provided code written in pascal, so I tried to convert it to cpp rigorously while also checking against the formulas I was given. I also implemented a program that calculated the DFT through a simple matrix multiplication to compare the results.

Comment: It is conventional to compute `FFT(N, xreal, yreal)` with N restricted to powers of 2 and not sensible to limit array dimensions inside FFT to [100] which isn't a power of two! Try testing it on an 8 length vector with simple low frequency sine waves as test input and you will probably be able to see where you are going wrong.  Then retry with sin waves on 16. You chose the more difficult way to do it with the bitreverse applied to the sin,cos coefficients. Most practitioners use recurrence relations to generate sin(2piP/N) in sequence and unshuffle the array at the end. BTW set ximag to zero.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, I will try right now

Comment: Unrelated: `if(i > k) swap(xreal[k], xreal[i]), swap(ximag[k], ximag[i]);` is not faster than `if(i > k) { swap(xreal[k], xreal[i]); swap(ximag[k], ximag[i]); }` but it _is_ harder to read and more error prone.

Comment: If you have code in Pascal that works, then it should be simple to dump all variables from that code and compare their values to C++ one.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently overlooked the fact that the bit-reversal is supposed to happen on `gamma` bits; this was the whole problem.

The correct version of the `itbtr` function is:

```
int itbtr(int k, int gamma){
    int m = k;
    int newn = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < gamma; i++){
        newn *= 2;
        newn += m % 2;
        m /= 2;
    }
    return newn;
}
```

Comment: Explicit bit reversals like that are not performed at all in real implementations, here's a paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.01873